# How to fill in anRepeater.ItemTemplate from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, repeater

I know this is possible but I just don't know how to make it happen. I need to create multiple Repeater Controls from code behind in ASP.NET C#. I know how to create the repeater dynamically as well the HeaderTemplate and FooterTemplate. Where I'm having issues is on the ItemTemplate. I don't know how to bind the fields coming from the DataSource. I've seen many examples but none of them work.

This is how I'm building my HeaderTemplate:

```
TemplateBuilder hdr = new TemplateBuilder();
hdr.AppendLiteralString("<table><thead><tr><th>Team</th></tr></thead>");
```

And this is how I'm building my FooterTemplate:

```
TemplateBuilder ftr = new TemplateBuilder();
ftr.AppendLiteralString("</table>");
```

This is how I'm associating my templates to the repeater:

```
Repeater repeater1 = new Repeater();
repeater1.DataSource = Connections.isp_GET_GRIDVIEW_DATA("STDNG", group, "", "");
repeater1.HeaderTemplate = hdr;
repeater1.ItemTemplate = dtl;
repeater1.FooterTemplate = ftr;
repeater1.DataBind();
```

Now my issue is with this part of the code:

```
TemplateBuilder dtl = new TemplateBuilder();
dtl.AppendLiteralString(???);
```

How do I create the template for the repeater1.ItemTemplate? How can I bind the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, don't know if this is the best approach but its working

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.ComponentModel;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Repeater_Templates
/// </summary>
public class Repeater_Templates : ITemplate
{
   static int itemcount = 0;
   ListItemType templateType;

public Repeater_Templates(ListItemType type)
{
   templateType = type;
}

public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
{
   Literal lc = new Literal();
   switch( templateType )
   {
      case ListItemType.Header:
          lc.Text = "<table class=\"table zebra-striped\"><thead><tr><th>Equipo</th><th>J</th><th>G</th><th>E</th><th>P</th><th>G</th><th>E</th><th>D</th><th>PTS</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr>";
        break;
     case ListItemType.Item:
        lc.Text = "<td>";
        lc.DataBinding += new EventHandler(TemplateControl_DataBinding);
        break;
     case ListItemType.AlternatingItem:
        lc.Text = "<td>";
        lc.DataBinding += new EventHandler(TemplateControl_DataBinding);
        break;
     case ListItemType.Footer:
        lc.Text = "</tbody></table>";
        break;
  }
  container.Controls.Add(lc);
  itemcount += 1;
}

private void TemplateControl_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Literal lc;
    lc = (Literal)sender;
    RepeaterItem container = (RepeaterItem)lc.NamingContainer;
    lc.Text += "<img style=\"vertical-align:middle\" src=\"" + DataBinder.Eval(container.DataItem, "LOCATION") + "\" /> "
       + DataBinder.Eval(container.DataItem, "TEAM") + "</td><td>" + DataBinder.Eval(container.DataItem, "GAMES") + "</td><td>" + DataBinder.Eval(container.DataItem, "WON")
        + "</td><td>" + DataBinder.Eval(container.DataItem, "DRAW") + "</td><td>" + DataBinder.Eval(container.DataItem, "LOST") + "</td><td>" + DataBinder.Eval(container.DataItem, "GOALS")
         + "</td><td>" + DataBinder.Eval(container.DataItem, "AGAINST") + "</td><td>" + DataBinder.Eval(container.DataItem, "DIFFERENCE") + "</td><td>" + DataBinder.Eval(container.DataItem, "POINTS");
   lc.Text += "</td><tr>";
}
}
```

Hope it helps